# Where did Trampoline.S go?

Tags: linux, kernel

Dear all, I was wondering where the trampoline code went. It is referenced [here](http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v2.6.38/arch/x86/kernel/head_32.S#L269), and I could find some code in an earlier [distro](http://lxr.e2g.org/source/arch/i386/kernel/trampoline.S?v=s3c-linux.2.6.21), but I can't find it in the 2.6.38 kernel. Can you explain to me the path of execution, if `trampoline.S` is not there anymore? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When the [x86_64 a.k.a. amd64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86-64) architecture was introduced in the Linux kernel tree, it was in a separate subtree from i386. So there was [`arch/i386/kernel/trampoline.S`](http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v2.6.23/arch/i386/kernel/trampoline.S) on one side and [`arch/x86_64/kernel/trampoline.S`](http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v2.6.23/arch/x86_64/kernel/trampoline.S) on the other side.

[The two architectures were merged in 2.6.24](http://lwn.net/Articles/243704/). This was done because there was a lot of code in common — after all, all x86-64 processors are x86 processors. At the time, ppc and ppc64 were already together, and it was decided to merge x86 and x86-64 as well, into a single [`x86`](http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v2.6.24/arch/x86/) architecture.

Some files are specific to one or the other subarchitectures, so the two versions remain alongside each other: [`arch/x86/kernel/trampoline_32.S`](http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v2.6.24/arch/x86/kernel/trampoline_32.S) [moved from `arch/i386/kernel/trampoline.S`](http://git.kernel.org/?p=linux/kernel/git/stable/linux-2.6.27.y.git;a=history;f=arch/x86/kernel/trampoline_32.S;h=d8ccc3c6552f60f85bd50de1d4e6c68548261ae7;hb=666bc219c81eeaf90cb6171dcfee4ef322abcde3), and [`arch/x86/kernel/trampoline_64.S`](http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v2.6.24/arch/x86/kernel/trampoline_64.S) [moved from `arch/x86_64/kernel/trampoline.S`](http://git.kernel.org/?p=linux/kernel/git/stable/linux-2.6.27.y.git;a=history;f=arch/x86/kernel/trampoline_64.S;h=894293c598db62fe6b23a365d048c8a6225a8285;hb=666bc219c81eeaf90cb6171dcfee4ef322abcde3).